# Data validation before next dialog waterfall step in Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, validation, botframework

Have simple waterfall dialog:

```
SendMessageDialog = [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.time(session, "Enter dates?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.conversationData.start = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]).toISOString();

        if(typeof results.response.resolution.end != "undefined")
            session.conversationData.end = results.response.resolution.end.toISOString();
    }
];
```

Bot successfully recognizes time in different formats, and if format is invalid makes default prompt to user proposing to re-enter data like:

> I didn't understand. Please choose an option from the list.

In `Prompts` option I can only change this default `retryPrompt` message. What if I need additional validation like:

- User enters a date, but the date isn't valid because of business
  logic (in the past, unavailable)
- User enters a location, so need to check against list of available locations (perhaps from an api call)
- Check number range after `Prompts.number()`
- etc

Is there is an easy way to **add additional validation to retry same waterfall step** and ask user to re-enter data? How to implement this? Is there a workable code for BotBuilder 3.9?

There are [some examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2741#issuecomment-307430385) exist to make some validations with LUIS API calls, however they work only on next waterfall step. Goal not to go to the next step until correct data entered - is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the question was asked, had found how-to [Create custom prompts to validate input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace#create-custom-prompts-to-validate-input):

**Result code:**

```
[
    function (session) {
        // Call start/end time prompt dialog
        session.beginDialog("DatePromptDialog");
    },
    ...
]

DatePromptDialog = [
    function (session, args) {
        var options = { retryPrompt: "I didn’t recognize dates you entered. Please try again using format: start - end dates" };

        if (args && args.reprompt && args.endTimeMissed) {
            builder.Prompts.time(session, "Please specify both start - end times:", options);
        } else if (args && args.reprompt && args.dateInPast){
            builder.Prompts.time(session, "That date seems to be in the past! Please enter a valid date.", options);
        } else {
            builder.Prompts.time(session, "Enter dates?", options);
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        var args = {};
        delete session.conversationData.start;  // Clear previous values
        delete session.conversationData.end;

        // Get start time
        session.conversationData.start = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]).toISOString();
        // Get duration end time if available
        if(typeof results.response.resolution.end != "undefined")
            session.conversationData.end = results.response.resolution.end.toISOString();
        else {
            args.endTimeMissed = true;
            args.reprompt = true;
        }

        // Convert dates from string
        var currDate = new Date(); // Current date
        var startDate = new Date(session.conversationData.start);
        var endDate = new Date(session.conversationData.end);

        if(startDate < currDate || endDate < currDate) {
            args.dateInPast = true;
            args.reprompt = true;
        }

        if (args.reprompt) {
            // Repeat the dialog
            session.replaceDialog('DatePromptDialog', args);
        } else {
            // Success
            session.endDialog();
        }
    }
];
```